# Android Use MaterialDrawer(Library) with FlowingDrawer(Library)

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, materialdrawer

Before we begin, it would be better to take a look at those two libraries

MaterialDrawer - https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer

FlowingDrawer - https://github.com/mxn21/FlowingDrawer

I'm currently using MaterialDrawer.
Witch allows me super fast drawer implementation, maintaining, ect..

for that reason i cant give up this library, still i'd love to use FlowingDrawer which provides super cool drawer effect.

i came up with 2 possible options.

1. export View from MaterialDrawer, insert this into FlowingDrawer.
2. editing the MaterialDrawer's code to be implemented by FlowingDrawer.

i'm not even sure if both suggestions would work.

tell me your thoughts! better if solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MaterialDrawer requires a `DrawerLayout`. The FlowingDrawer implements no `DrawerLayout` thus it is not possible. Modifying the `MaterialDrawer`'s code sounds like a huge effort as the methods of and functions of the `DrawerLayout` are used in many different places.

My suggestion would be to use the `View` the `MaterialDrawer` generates. Have a look at the `EmbeddedDrawerActivity` which actually does exactly this. It creates the `MaterialDrawer` and then uses the `View` of it and adds it to the root.

```
result = new DrawerBuilder()
        .withActivity(this)
        .withToolbar(toolbar)
        .withTranslucentStatusBar(false)
        .withAccountHeader(headerResult)
        .addDrawerItems(
            ...
        )
        .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
        .buildView();

View drawerView = result.getSlider();
```

Comment: how could i possibly use that view to `FlowingDrawer` ?? by code

Comment: Perfect!!! needed some more research. but stiill its soooo cooool!! // Thank you!

Comment: @uzu please accept the answer if it is solving your issue